# Can I get the index of a string where a mouse event clicks?

Tags: javascript

If I have a div with multiple elements, is there a way for a click mouse event to give me the index at which the click ocured in that element ? [JsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/9ef5pavL/2/)

```js
mainDiv.addEventListener('click', (e)=>{
  console.log(e.target)
  // Exact index of the click ?
})
```

```css
#mainDiv{
  height: 300px;
  width: 300px;
  background: #1f2227;
  color: white;
  white-space: pre-wrap;
}

body{
  margin: 0;
}
```

```html
<div id='mainDiv'>
   <span>Some Text</span>
   <span>Some Other Text</span>
   <span>More text here</span>
</div>
```

My first though was to use the coordinates of the click event `clientX:`, `clientY:` and check what element is at that spot on the page, but I'm still not sure how to get the exact location in that element.

The `event.target` already gives me the clicked element, can I the exact position in the element too somehow ?

```
Some text in a span in a div
   ^ Click occurs there
e.target give me the element clicked, can I get the index ?
Like click occurred on span element at index 3 ?
```

The only way I can think of is to use the coordinates of the event, but maybe there's some other way.

Comment: The easiest way would be to just wrap every character in a <span> tag

Comment: check this out https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7457577/onclick-index-in-string but using Jquery solution

Comment: @idmean Wrapping every letter would work, but the text already gets parsed and get's surrounded by HTML for highlighting and stuff like that, on a long text that's that's a lot of element that need to constantly be parsed.

Comment: @RDU Have you really looked at the answers? Several answers there highlight how to do this without spans.

Comment: @idmean Yup i found it, looks like using `getSelection()`  and `getRangeAt()` is the way to go, thank you.