# TextView parse words to be clickable

Tags: android, textview, onclicklistener

hi  i have a sentence  (TextView) and I want to tap a certain word and I want to show this word in Toast, e.g. I would like to set the OnClickLister to be able to grab a word, wich was tapped, not the whole sentence

**for example**

sentence TextView ---   I love stackoverflow

tap  on "love"  ----->  toast the word "love"

I've only come up with the idea of creating many TextViews, and set listners for each one...it can't be good...
Do you have any ideas how to implement this?

maybe there are some libraries for word processing I'm not aware of?

Comment: So, you are trying to implement this with one TextView, right ?

Comment: yes, are there any other options?

Comment: Yeah, I was about to say so but looks like some has already answered it. I guess that would be enough to solve your problem. :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[select a word on a tap in TextView/EditText](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8612652/select-a-word-on-a-tap-in-textview-edittext)

see the above question. I think it may solve your problem. You need not have one textview for each word. Have one textview for the whole sentence. then catch the word clicked. I think that is wat is explained above.

Please let me know if this helped.

Answer (score 0):

An alternate solution to setting a ClickableSpan for each word (as the reference in @LakshmiNarayanan's answer suggested) would be to set an `OnTouchListener` on the `TextView`. Then in the `onTouch` method you can get the offset of the character that has been touched like this:

```
Layout layout = this.getLayout();
if (layout != null)
{
    int line = layout.getLineForVertical(motionEvent.getY()); 
    int offset = layout.getOffsetForHorizontal(line, motionEvent.getX());
}
```

After that you could use a [BreakIterator](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/text/BreakIterator.html) or your own implementation to return the word that was touched.