# EditText, get word at both sides of the focus

Tags: android, android-edittext, textwatcher

I have an EditText and when i tap anywhere in the middle of a word, i want to be able to extract that word.

I know that i have to use `getSelectionStart()` and `getSelectionEnd()` methods, but i cannot make it work.

Can someone help me?

This is my code so far, on my onTextChanged method:

```
int cursorPosition = editMain.getSelectionStart();

        editMain.setOnTouchListener(new OnTouchListener() {

            @Override
            public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
                String selectedText = editMain
                        .getText()
                        .toString()
                        .substring(editMain.getSelectionStart(),
                                editMain.getSelectionEnd());

                buttonPopupHashtag.setText(selectedText);
                return false;

            }
        });
```

The problem is that i need to tap twice to get the word and i want it with a single tap.

Comment: Please post your code and logcat output if application is being crashed

Comment: @ShreyaShah OP didn't mentioned anything like crash?

Comment: @Padma Kumar, I just asked "if it is being crashed". Because OP just mentioned "i cannot make it work"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe you will want to look at the next link. User already asked for it and there is a piece of code provided there doing what you requested: [select a word on a tap in TextView/EditText](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8612652/select-a-word-on-a-tap-in-textview-edittext)