# How to make one word in a TextView with a long text from a string clickable?

Tags: java, android, string, textview

I have a little question about coding in Java on Android.

So, I have one TextView with a long text from a string. I want to make only one word of this long text clickable, that I can link it to an other Activity.

By the way, I'm new to the Android development, so please don't explain your solution too complicated. Thanks! :)

I have no idea, how I could do this. I also googled after a solution before but didn't find a clear way that worked well. Anyway, I would appreciate your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, you're **lucky**.
It seems to be **possible**: see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10696986/how-to-set-the-part-of-the-text-view-is-clickable) link.
Another method could be to put an hyperlink in your string.

Comment: Ok I tried your solution a few times and finally got it to work! :D Thank you ver much! :)

Answer (score 2):

What is the outcome you want for the click?

The simplest way to do this would be to apply a [`URLSpan`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/style/URLSpan.html) onto the TextView's contents, but if you want to do something other than view a webpage you can implement your own version of [`ClickableSpan`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/style/ClickableSpan.html) and make the click do whatever you want.

Edit per your comment:

Making a ClickableSpan go to another activity is really easy, here's the start of the code you'd need for it:

```
public class MyURLSpan extends ClickableSpan {
        Class<?> mClassToLaunch;

        public MyURLSpan(Class<?> classToLaunch) {
                mClassToLaunch = classToLaunch;
        }

        @Override
        public void onClick(View widget) {
                Intent intent = new Intent(widget.getContext(), mClassToLaunch);
                widget.getContext().startActivity(intent);
        }

        @Override
        public void updateDrawState(TextPaint ds) {
                // If you don't want the default drawstate (blue-underline), comment this super call out.
                super.updateDrawState(ds);
        }
}
```

Then to use it:

```
String longText = "your text goes here...";

SpannableString textViewContents = new SpannableString(longText);
textViewContents.setSpan(new MyURLSpan(NextActivity.class), indexToStart, lengthOfClickArea, Spannable.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);

myTextView.setText(textViewContents);
```

Comment: Sorry I forgot to tell this... I will add it. So, I want to link that one word to an other activity.

Comment: @Piezord Added some example code :) (Wrote it by hand so I don't think it'll compile without actually checking some of it)

Comment: Thank you but I have an error in the following line: `textViewContents.setSpan(new MyURLSpan(extras.class), indexToStart, lengthOfClickArea,` . I get the error: Syntax error on token(s), misplaced construct(s) So, what does this mean, what shall I do here?

Comment: Those are words I put in there to tell you that actual values need to go there instead :) Look at the description of [setSpan](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/Spannable.html) to see what to use.

Comment: I'm sorry but I don't get it. :/ So, you see I'm really new to the Android Development. Perhaps you can explain it yet a bit easier? :) Maybe which words I need to change. Maybe wrote this words is " " or something like that? That would be so nice. :) (Btw I'm not English, that makes it a bit more difficult for me to understand...)

Comment: Ok. I got an other solution but anyway, thank you very much! :)

Answer (score 0):

You can create a TextView per-word, and add them to a FlowLayout. Then you can assign OnClick events to any view you want.

The sentance "This is a test" would actually be made up of 4 TextViews, all inside some Layout (maybe a FlowLayout).

There's some details about a FlowLayout in this SO post:

[How can I do something like a FlowLayout in Android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4474237/how-can-i-do-something-like-a-flowlayout-in-android)

Answer (score 0):

i did not try this but i think if you use below hint then may be You will success.
txt.setText(Html.fromHtml("...link..."));
txt.setMovementMethod(LinkMovementMethod.getInstance());

[select a word on a tap in TextView/EditText](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8612652/select-a-word-on-a-tap-in-textview-edittext)

i think it will help.