# How to build a keyboard app sending clickable images?

Tags: android, android-input-method

Is that possible to create a keyboard app sending some images on chat apps (like Whatsapp), which would be clickable by the receiver if he has the keyboard app installed? A click on an image should play a sound.

I have checked the doc on [creating an input method](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/text/creating-input-method.html), but can't find anything about clickable items. I guess the app should send some id to display the corresponding image, which could be used to get the right audio file too, but I have no idea how to do it.

Any pointers/comments anyone?

Comment: Consider following example, For emoticons, the mapping is used in which the emoticon has a particular unicode. So when an emoticon is used in message the corresponding unicode is sent. On receiving it at other end the client application uses emoticon corresponding to that emoticon. I think you can use this and map the audio file accordingly.

Comment: @Ritesh Gune: thanks, but how can I catch a click on the emoticon on the receiver side?

Comment: See this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8612652/select-a-word-on-a-tap-in-textview-edittext