# Clickable every single separate word in TextView invoking a dialog containing selected word

Tags: android, textview, clickable, selectable

I apologize for that horrible title but I want to be accurate.

I have ScrollView in that LinearView and in that I dynamically create multiple rows filled with  sentences by TextView.
I set different collors created using SpannableText but I don't know ho to make every single word of that TextView responding the way I want - pop dialog question that will contain this word and ask me what I want to do with it. 
I want to move it to EditText in next fragment.. only that..

Please, what kind of magic would be the most suitable for this event? And maybe a kick with little example on one sentence.

Comment: Use [ClickableSpan](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/style/ClickableSpan.html) to the words that you want to response to click event.

Comment: Thank you, I found one superb solution in answers of "Related" questions. This question is [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8612652/select-a-word-on-a-tap-in-textview-edittext). One thing I don't know is how to make text again red or .. normal like it was before adding that onClick event..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are much more you can do with [Spannable](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/Spannable.html), [this blog post](http://flavienlaurent.com/blog/2014/01/31/spans/) has everything about Spannable, and it should be able to help you.

If you don't want to read the whole blog, than here is the short answer.

Use [ForegroundColorSpan](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/style/ForegroundColorSpan.html).

```
SpannableString ss = new SpannableString("Color text");
ForegroundColorSpan span = new ForegroundColorSpan(Color.RED);
ss.setSpan(span, 0, ss.length(), 0);
```