# How to set ClickableSpan's color once clicked and keep the color until clicked elsewhere?

Tags: android, html, spannablestring, clickablespan

Here's a [a link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8612652/select-a-word-on-a-tap-in-textview-edittext/) about how to select a word in textview on single tap. I want to make the word selected change the background color to grey and keep grey until the user click elsewhere. However, I have extended `LinkMovementMethod` to the `textview`, but this way is not able to reverse the background color to transparent when I click else where.

Here is the example of my failed attempt.
[image]

In other words, at most one word is highlighted. How to achieve that?

Answer (score 0):

You can store start and end of the word you highlited. And when user clicks other word just remove old span, override start and end variable and mark new word.

Comment: I understand your idea. Could you give specific code?

Comment: Code? Just create variables for start and stop. Than according to the method from link you've attached use spannableString to set/reset background

Comment: How to get start and stop in `onClick`?

Comment: Pass it to getClickableSpan method as argument

Comment: Sorry, I still don't understand. I would appreciate if you post your code sample.

Comment: I mean if the user click somewhere else besides other word, the background color should be removed as well.