# get position of the text inside a TextView

Tags: android, textview

suppose I have the following text 'ADD TEST' inside `TextView` as shown below 
[image]

as you can see the text inside the `TextView` does not have the same width and height as `TextView` .

what I want is to get the x,y position of text inside the `TextView`

Comment: `android:includeFontPadding="false"`  can remove that extra space then the x,y position of text will be same as textView

Comment: @Ashwini Violet it tried it i didn't work

Comment: Can you tell me why your need that position.. I'm just curious if you don't mind

Comment: @Ashwini Violet ,i want to send the x.y position of text to the server so i can draw them again from the serve side at the same position .So i either need the text to be exactly the same as textView (better solution) or the x,y position of text inside it .

Comment: @ Ashwini Violet it looks like android:includeFontPadding="false" decreased the height of the textview but it still not the same

Comment: `android:includeFontPadding="false" android:scaleY="1.5"` use these two..it can help you...see if this is what you want @has19

Comment: @AshwiniViolet although its better but its still  not exactly the same ,i don't think you can do it like that

Comment: Yes i know that's way it's a comment not an answer... Let's see if someone come with more bright idea @has19

Comment: @Ashwini Violet  haha i know man ,thx anyway

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Take a look at a couple of `Paint` methods: [`getTextBounds()`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Paint.html#getTextBounds(java.lang.String,%20int,%20int,%20android.graphics.Rect)) and [`measureText`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Paint.html#measureText(java.lang.String,%20int,%20int)). We can use these to determine the offset of the text within the `TextView`. Once the offset within the `TextView` is determined, we can add that to the location of the `TextView` itself to determine the screen coordinates of the text if that is desired.

I have also found the article ["Android 101: Typography"](https://proandroiddev.com/android-and-typography-101-5f06722dd611) to be useful in understanding some of the complexities of typography.

The following example finds the bounds of the text within three `TextViews` and draws a rectangle around the text. The rectangle contains the (x, y) coordinates of the text within the `TextView`.

**activity_main.xml**
A simple layout for demonstration.

```
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
    android:id="@+id/layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="24dp"
        android:background="@android:color/holo_blue_light"
        android:padding="24dp"
        android:text="Hello World"
        android:textColor="@android:color/black"
        android:textSize="50sp"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="24dp"
        android:background="@android:color/holo_blue_light"
        android:padding="24dp"
        android:text="Hello Worldly"
        android:textColor="@android:color/black"
        android:textSize="50sp"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/textView1" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView3"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="24dp"
        android:background="@android:color/holo_blue_light"
        android:padding="24dp"
        android:text="aaaaaaaaaa"
        android:textColor="@android:color/black"
        android:textSize="50sp"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/textView2" />

</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

**MainActivity.java**

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        drawTextBounds((TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView1));
        drawTextBounds((TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView2));
        drawTextBounds((TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView3));
    }

    private void drawTextBounds(TextView textView) {
        // Force measure of text pre-layout.
        textView.measure(0, 0);
        String s = (String) textView.getText();

        // bounds will store the rectangle that will circumscribe the text.
        Rect bounds = new Rect();
        Paint textPaint = textView.getPaint();

        // Get the bounds for the text. Top and bottom are measured from the baseline. Left
        // and right are measured from 0.
        textPaint.getTextBounds(s, 0, s.length(), bounds);
        int baseline = textView.getBaseline();
        bounds.top = baseline + bounds.top;
        bounds.bottom = baseline + bounds.bottom;
        int startPadding = textView.getPaddingStart();
        bounds.left += startPadding;

        // textPaint.getTextBounds() has already computed a value for the width of the text, 
        // however, Paint#measureText() gives a more accurate value.
        bounds.right = (int) textPaint.measureText(s, 0, s.length()) + startPadding;

        // At this point, (x, y) of the text within the TextView is (bounds.left, bounds.top)
        // Draw the bounding rectangle.
        Bitmap bitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(textView.getMeasuredWidth(),
                                            textView.getMeasuredHeight(),
                                            Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
        Canvas canvas = new Canvas(bitmap);
        Paint rectPaint = new Paint();
        rectPaint.setColor(Color.RED);
        rectPaint.setStyle(Paint.Style.STROKE);
        rectPaint.setStrokeWidth(1);
        canvas.drawRect(bounds, rectPaint);
        textView.setForeground(new BitmapDrawable(getResources(), bitmap));
    }
}
```

[image]

Comment: But it is not working when TextView.gravity=center(or end),any other solution?

Comment: in case someone wants the char position when knows the char index https://stackoverflow.com/a/56740416/2736039

Answer (score 3):

**Y value**

You can use `textView.getTextSize()` or `textView.getPaint().getTextSize()` to get the actual used text size in pixels (as `Float`).

Next, we need the total height of the text view, which we can find as follows:

```
textView.measure(0, 0); // We must call this to let it calculate the heights
int height = textView.getMeasuredHeight();
```

However, the final size that we need can also have decimals. So lets make it a float for more precision:

```
float totalHeight = (float) height;
```

Now that we know the values, we can calculate the y value of the text inside the view:

```
// The spacing between the views is `totalHeight - textSize`
// We have a spacing at the top and the bottom, so we divide it by 2
float yValue = (totalHeight - textSize) / 2
```

**X value**

Furthermore, the xValue is just the x value of the text view itself when using 
`android:includeFontPadding="false"`.

Answer (score 1):

Here is the solution I came up with, it supports multiple lines text and also changing the **gravity** attribute. Below is the result image and the source code:

[image]

```
import android.content.Context
import android.graphics.*
import android.util.AttributeSet
import androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatTextView


class CustomTextView : AppCompatTextView {

    constructor(context: Context) : super(context)
    constructor(context: Context, attrs: AttributeSet?) : super(context, attrs)
    constructor(context: Context, attrs: AttributeSet?, defStyleAttr: Int) : super(context, attrs, defStyleAttr)

    val textPaint: Paint = Paint().apply {
        isAntiAlias = true
        style = Paint.Style.STROKE
        strokeWidth = 2f
    }

    val bounds = ArrayList<Rect>()
    val fullBounds = Rect()

    override fun onMeasure(widthMeasureSpec: Int, heightMeasureSpec: Int) {
        super.onMeasure(widthMeasureSpec, heightMeasureSpec)
        getBound()
    }

    private fun getBound() {

        text.toString().let { string ->

            val lines = string.split("\n")
            var offset = 0

            lines.forEachIndexed { i, str ->

                // replace all tabs with _ char for measuring
                val s = str.replace('\t', '_')

                // get horizontal bound for each line
                val boundHorizontal = Rect()
                paint.getTextBounds(s, 0, s.length, boundHorizontal)
                boundHorizontal.offset(
                    paddingStart + (layout?.getPrimaryHorizontal(offset)?.toInt() ?: 0),
                    0
                )

                // get vertical bound for each line
                val boundVertical = Rect()
                getLineBounds(i, boundVertical)
                boundVertical.apply {
                    left = boundHorizontal.left
                    right = boundHorizontal.right
                }
                bounds.add(boundVertical)

                offset += (s.length + 1)
            }

            bounds.forEachIndexed { i, rect ->
                if (i == 0) {
                    fullBounds.set(rect)
                }
                fullBounds.intersectUnchecked(rect)
            }
        }
    }

    override fun onDraw(canvas: Canvas) {

        canvas.drawRect(fullBounds, textPaint.apply { color = Color.YELLOW })

        bounds.forEach {
            canvas.drawRect(it, textPaint.apply { color = Color.MAGENTA })
        }

        super.onDraw(canvas)
    }

    companion object {

        fun Rect.intersectUnchecked(other: Rect) {
            if (other.left < left) left = other.left
            if (other.right > right) right = other.right
            if (other.top < top) top = other.top
            if (other.bottom > bottom) bottom = other.bottom
        }
    }
}
```

And then add your custom view via XML:

```
<com.slaviboy.universaldictionarybg.ApostropheTextView
        android:layout_width="150dp"
        android:layout_height="200dp"
        android:background="#41BADF"
        android:gravity="end|bottom"
        android:includeFontPadding="false"
        android:lineSpacingExtra="0dp"
        android:text="This\nis\nmultiline\ntest :D"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />
```

Comment: Doesn't work when text is wrapped into a new line without '\n'