# How to get the String screen location(y and x) from textView in android?

Tags: android, textview

I need to locate some of the string's location from the `TextView` so that I can move my `imageView's` location to that certain location inside `Textview` to show my `gif` images using `glide` in `recyclerView`.

This is what I've than so far:
[image]

I replaced the previous string with space to transfer my imageview on that certain position but before I will replace it with space I need to locate the string's position on the screen from the position of the string inside textview.

Comment: can you provide a screen shot of your desirable?

Comment: is the cursor/focus active i.e you can get location of cursor in the textView but location of some text in text View is not possible with TextView APi's

Comment: Possible duplicate of [get position of the text inside a TextView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52428868/get-position-of-the-text-inside-a-textview)

Comment: I think this is not a duplicate. OP seems wants to know the absolute position of a TextView, while this "possible duplicate" asks to get real width / height.

Comment: @nikhilbansal I have added the screenshot, that's what I'm trying to achieve.

Comment: @Anmol What I did was on the first load of the items from the adapter, each item will be parse by getting the string on that certain textview. Can I now what certain TextView API's that are not capable of detecting the location?

Comment: so you want to place the image where u put the space now? Please clear the use case to get a better solution.

Comment: @nikhilbansal sorry for getting you confused. What I'm trying to achieve is to only get the string position, I'll handle the space parsing. So let's just think that I did not remove those string and replace with space. How can I get that certain string position from that textview? After that, I will set my Imageview's  position on that certain position.