# Android - How to get the coordinates of a character in a textview

Tags: android, char, textview, character, coordinates

Is it possible to get the x coordinate from a character in a TextView in Android?
I'm not looking for the coordinate of the TextView itself, I need the coordinate of the last character in the TextView (multi line)

Thanks in advance

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Find exact coordinates of a single Character inside a TextView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18257321/find-exact-coordinates-of-a-single-character-inside-a-textview)

Answer (score 7):

### Java Solution

Here is how to get the `x` *and* `y` coordinates of a specific character. `offset` is the index of the desired character in the textView's String. These coordinates are relative to the parent container

```
Layout layout = textView.getLayout();
if (layout == null) { // Layout may be null right after change to the text view
    // Do nothing
}

int lineOfText = layout.getLineForOffset(offset);
int xCoordinate = (int) layout.getPrimaryHorizontal(offset);
int yCoordinate = layout.getLineTop(lineOfText);
```

### Kotlin Extension Function

If you expect to use this more than once:

```
fun TextView.charLocation(offset: Int): Point? {
    layout ?: return null // Layout may be null right after change to the text view

    val lineOfText = layout.getLineForOffset(offset)
    val xCoordinate = layout.getPrimaryHorizontal(offset).toInt()
    val yCoordinate = layout.getLineTop(lineOfText)
    return Point(xCoordinate, yCoordinate) 
}
```

> **NOTE:** To ensure layout is **not null**, you can call `textview.post(() -> { /* get coordinates */ })` in Java or `textview.post { /* get coordinates */ }` in Kotlin

Answer (score 0):

Use:

```
layout.getPrimaryHorizontal(int offset)
```

It is simple to use. You just iterate through the layout using the length of the text it uses.

It will return the x of the Character . So lines I'm still getting from the `layout.getLineTop()` . By the way, if you are using the `layout.getLineTop()` , note that there is some strange behaviour, possibly a bug.

Answer (score 0):

Given a span that has one or more paragraphs, try to get the last character of the entire span dosen't work. Is there another way to get the same result of getPrimaryHorizontal()?