# Get cursor position(coordinates) in BasicTextField Android Compose

Tags: android, android-layout, android-jetpack-compose

I want to get position (x, y) of current cursor when the user is typing in a BasicTextField. The BasicTextField is expandable and can cover full screen.

I need it to display suggestion list just on top of the written text

Something like this that follows TextField cursor

[image]

Comment: I am basically looking for this in compose
https://stackoverflow.com/a/56740295/6401064

Comment: Any luck finding a solution for this?  I am trying to do the same.

Answer (score 0):

This is my solution using a BasicTextField.

I'm using a `TextFieldValue` to keep the TextField string value and cursor position (accessible via `selection` field).
This value is updated within the `onValueChange{}` callback.

The two values we are looking for will be stored in `cursorYCoord` and `cursorXCoord`

In order to get `cursorYCoord`, we need to get first the `cursorLine`.
`cursorXCoord` is obtained within the `onTextLayout` callback

```
var textFieldValue by remember {
    mutableStateOf(TextFieldValue(description))
}
var textLayoutResult by remember {
    mutableStateOf<TextLayoutResult?>(null)
}
val cursorLine by remember {
    derivedStateOf { textLayoutResult?.getLineForOffset(textFieldValue.selection.start) ?: 0 }
}
val cursorYCoord by remember {
    derivedStateOf { (textLayoutResult?.getLineBottom(cursorLine) ?: 0f).toInt() }
}
var cursorXCoord by remember {
    mutableStateOf(0)
}


BasicTextField(
   [...]
   onValueChange = {
        textFieldValue = it
    },
    onTextLayout = {
        textLayoutResult = it

        cursorXCoord = it.getHorizontalPosition(textFieldValue.selection.start, true).toInt()
    },
   [...]
```

Comment: How do we get the cursor position when the TextField has scrolling, in this case, cursorYCoord exceeds max height