# find string at pixel position in textview

Tags: android, drag-and-drop, textview, indexof

I have a fullscreen `TextView` with a very long text, ie. like a story with say 400 lines.

I would like to be able to drop icons into the TextView, then insert some text **in the position where the  icon was dropped**.

For example, i drop the icon at the coordinates 400,1700 and that corresponds to the word 'especialmente' at the string position 597 (see screenshot)

I have the DnD thing done, however, I don't know how to calculate the `indexOf` of the `TextView` from the droped coordinates.

[image]

Is there a simple way to do it ? Or this will get that complex so as to create `StaticLayout`'s and a ton of math?

Comment: Spannable string might address some of your concerns. Better use it as a starting point.

Comment: I already use spannable strings for indentation, links, format and for inserting images into the text, but I don't see how can I use it to calculate the substring from a pixel position, can you please be more specific?

Comment: Found the answer here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2302867/android-how-to-determine-character-index-of-a-touch-events-position-in-textvie :)