# Wrong value returned by getOffsetForPosition

Tags: android

I want to color the letter I click on in a TextView, so to get the offset I use

```
getOffsetForPosition(event.getX(), event.getY());
```

You can clearly see in the image below I click on 'o' in Genymotion (also on Galaxy S4). Why does it say I click on 'h'?

What can be the problem?

[[image: 1]]

Comment: have you tried doing `getOffsetForPosition(x,y)-1`? I think its following the same behaviour as when you tap on a edittext and the cursor appears on the next letter.

Comment: Just reverses the problem... If at the begging clicking in the middle of letter 1 colored letter 2, now to click in the middle of letter 2 colors letter 1... If only it was possible to decrease by 0.5...

Comment: How about this solution? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2302867/android-how-to-determine-character-index-of-a-touch-events-position-in-textvie

Comment: getTextBounds didn't help but measureText seems to be good! 
Now I need to test this to see if there are hidden problems.